# how to get Sum of Column total in rad grid footer

Tags: .net, telerik, radgrid

how to get Sum of Column total in rad grid footer.

I tried like

```
<telerik:GridNumericColumn UniqueName="Amount" DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" FooterAggregateFormatString="{0}" DataType="System.Int32" Aggregate="Sum"> 
</telerik:GridNumericColumn>
```

Comment: You should add your code that you currently have. We not write your programm.

Answer (score 0):

```
int total=0;
for (int i=0; i < list.size(); i++){
    total = total + list.get(i).price;
}
Log.e("sum of column", total + " - " );
```

Comment: Please explain why this code fragment would help with the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to their manual this should be working just fine

`<telerik:GridNumericColumn UniqueName="Amount" DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" DataFormatString="{0:C}" DataType="System.Double" Aggregate="Sum"> 
</telerik:GridNumericColumn>`